# JSTL: display N items from a list

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a Java list:

```
List<Item> items;
```

I can iterate over it like this:

```
 <div class='items'>
   <c:forEach items="${requestScope.items}" var="item">
      <div class="item">
         <img class="item-image" src="${item.getImage()}"/>
         <p>${item.getName()}</p>
      </div>
   </c:forEach>
</div>
```

However there are around 1000 items and I only want to display 10 at once. Like this:

[image]

I know there is a usual for loop:

```
<c:forEach begin="6" end="15" var="val">
    <c:out value="${val}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

but I'm not sure how to access an ith element and how to make the press of the Next button display the next 10 items.

Answer (score 0):

To access an element in your list you can use:
    ${items[n]}
like an Array

For next button you can call your jsp (i suppose) giving a begin and a end parameters to show what you want

Comment: Can you give me more details, like, for example, your entire jsp? So we can discuss better